# Problem merging strings in pandas dataframe - encoding issue?

Tags: python, string, pandas, encoding, merge

I've been trying to merge strings in Pandas; most of them work, but some don't match, despite appearing to be exactly the same in the excel files.

```
data looks like:
File Name: company 1.pdf; Security Name: Series A Common
File Name: company 2.pdf; Security Name: Series B Common

ra1['File Name'] = ra1['File Name'].astype(str)
ra1['Security Name'] = ra1['Security Name'].astype(str)

ra1['Security Name 2'] = ra1['Security Name'].str.replace(" ","")


ra2['File Name'] = ra2['File Name'].astype(str)
ra2['Security Name'] = ra2['Security Name'].astype(str)

ra2['Security Name 2'] = ra2['Security Name'].str.replace(" ","")

x = pd.merge(ra1,ra2,on=['File Name','Security Name 2'],how='left')
```

I notice that after stripping white space, some of the series names in the first dataset still have a space, while it seems the equivalent in the second dataset do not, so the merge fails for those ones. For example Stock ACommon, vs StockACommon. dtypes say objects. These were in excel files; tried changing the columns to text in excel, but doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The code you have posted defines `ra2['Security Name']` after `ra2['Security Name 2]`

Comment: @SimonCrane thanks - fixed

Comment: What is the encoding of the Excel files? If you cut and paste the "different space character" from an excel file, into the `str.replace()` fct, is there any change in behavior? I'm wondering if you have a space this is not a space, similar to the "full width parenthese" (singular) that I have seen in Excel, which `str.replace("("))` rightly failed to replace.

Comment: @Evan so if I put that character into str.replace() as a new command, the space or character is eliminated in the new output. Also, If I check the equivalency of the strings against each other in Excel, they are not equivalent. However, if I type the same exact words into the cell they are then equivalent.

Comment: try using regex to remove the white space, `ra['Security Name'].str.replace('(\s+)','')`

Comment: @Ethe99 yw, added as answer:) couldn't find a similar duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding as an answer,

to match *all* white space such as `a     b    c` we can leverage a regular expression

#### `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ])`

#### `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

```
ra['Security Name'] = ra['Security Name'].str.replace('(\s+)','')
out:
Security Name
abc
```

regex demo :

https://regex101.com/r/3oyYte/1